# How to apply slide animation between two activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I want to achieve a sliding effect from left to right when I move from one activity to another. For that I am using the following code, but I am not getting any results. Please correct me.

In java both files:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Two files in res/anim directory:

**fadein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" >
</alpha>
```

**fadeout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" >
</alpha>
```

Comment: I used this code: `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);` You can see these examples in [GmailAnimation](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/GmailAnimation) or [LopeAnimations](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/LopeAnimations). Also you can see more in this [Blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/gmail-overriding-pending-transition/#sthash.CEhJwJLg.dpbs).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {

                     /* Create an intent that will start the main activity. */
                     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                             ConnectedActivity.class);
                     mainIntent.putExtra("id", "1");

                     //SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                     startActivity(mainIntent);
                     /* Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it. */
                     SplashScreen.this.finish();

                     /* Apply our splash exit (fade out) and main
                        entry (fade in) animation transitions. */
                     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,R.anim.splashfadeout);
             }
     }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);   
    }
```

Comment: Please don't do this kind of delayed Activity start! It will start your MainActivity even if your app is not in foreground anymore.

Answer (score 178):

Add this two file in res/anim folder.

**R.anim.slide_out_bottom**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/time_duration_max"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**R.anim.slide_in_bottom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
    android:duration="@integer/time_duration_max"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" /> 
</set>
```

And write the below line of code in your view click listener.

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NameOfTargetActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_bottom, R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
```

Comment: Thanks - Now how where should i put the reverse animation when going back to the old activity by pressing the back button

Comment: @EmAe, I've asked a similar question, and answerred it myself over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711666/activity-change-animation-with-popenter-and-popexit-animations/41025993#41025993. Hope it'll help you!

Comment: @Born To Win if possible can you add reverse animation.

Comment: aren't those anim the wrong way round? It's (enterAnim, exitAnim)

Answer (score 141):

[image]

You can overwrite your default activity animation and it perform better than overridePendingTransition. I use this solution that work for every android version. Just copy paste 4 files and add a 4 lines style as below:

Create a "CustomActivityAnimation" and add this to your base Theme by "windowAnimationStyle".

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>

</style>

<style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_left</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
</style>
```

Then Create anim folder under res folder and then create this four animation files into anim folder:

slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
</set>
```

If you face any problem then you can download my [sample project from github](https://github.com/ShohanAhmed/Android-Activity-Transition-Custom-Animation.git).

Thanks

Comment: I am using android 6 Huawei and its performing very well. :)

Comment: very nice ..work very good..we don't need to add in all intent that's advantage of this method..thans shohan

Comment: It works on API levels 17,24 but it does NOT work in API 25 !!!!!! why?

Comment: I love these kind of solutions! Put it in one place and works everywhere like a charm!

Comment: This is the best solution. No need to code in Java/Kotlin. Just put these XML files and everything is done easily.

Comment: This is a magic solution and deserves a 1000 upvotes. Very rarely you find simple and elegant solutions like this. And best of all, no ugly long coding is needed, just simple XML does it all.

Comment: Worked like a charm on API 29!

Comment: Where is the USAGE syntax code in this answer?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Its don't need any kotlin/java code. Just mention the app theme from the manifest. You can check the sample Github project.

Comment: @Zagfai are you sure? My device is also Android 10 & it's working fine.

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan It not work for me. It does not have error but all animation gone.

Answer (score 27):

Slide up/down with alpha animation with a few note

[image]

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/activity_transition_time"
    >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:toAlpha="1"/>
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/activity_transition_time"
    >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.5"/>
</set>
```

**no_animation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@integer/activity_transition_time"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"/>
```

**First Activity**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,  R.anim.no_animation); // remember to put it after startActivity, if you put it to above, animation will not working
// document say if we don't want animation we can put 0. However, if we put 0 instead of R.anim.no_animation, the exist activity will become black when animate
```

**Second Activity**

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation, R.anim.slide_down);
```

**Done**

**MORE**
I try to make the slide animation like iOS animation when present a View Model  (like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deZobvh2064) but failed.

Looking at iOS present animation you will see: The animation from bottom with alpha (about 50%) then it go very fast then slower, the animation time is about > 500ms (I use trim video tools for count the animation time 
https://www.kapwing.com/trim-video so it can not exactly 100%)

Then I try to apply to android.
To make alpha I use `<alpha>` and success.
To make animation start faster than slower I use `android:interpolator="a decelerate interpolator"` but it almost failed.

There are 3 default `decelerate interpolator` in Android
`@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad` -> factor = 1
`@android:interpolator/decelerate_cubic` -> factor = 1.5
`@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint` _> factor = 2.5
(higher factor <=> animation start more faster from start and more slower at end)
Here is a good tutorial http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2013/10/android-animations-tutorial-5-more-on-interpolators/ for understand it

I tried 3 above I can not achieve like iOS, the animation can not start faster like iOS. Then I create a custom decelerateInterpolator wiht factor = 3 like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<decelerateInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:factor="3" />
```

and I increase the duration time from `500 -> 750`. It working well (very similar to iOS). However, it only working well in some device, in some device the animation is quite slow. Later on, I know that animation may different on different device (eg: some device will faster and some device will slower) so I can not make it the animation similar in all Android device. Therefore I don't use `interpolator`. I don't know if my testing is exactly 100% or not but I hope this experience help

Answer (score 4):

## Here is a Slide Animation for you.

[image]

Let's say you have two activities.

1. MovieDetailActivity
2. AllCastActivity

And on click of a Button, this happens.

[image]

### You can achieve this in 3 simple steps

**1) Enable Content Transition**

Go to your `style.xml` and add this line to enable the content transition.

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

**2) Write Default Enter and Exit Transition for your AllCastActivity**

```
public void setAnimation()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>20) {
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.LEFT);
        slide.setDuration(400);
        slide.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
    }
}
```

**3) Start Activity with Intent**

Write this method in Your `MovieDetailActivity` to start `AllCastActivity`

```
public void startActivity(){

Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putStringArrayListExtra(MOVIE_LIST, movie.getImages());

  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>20)
   {
       ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(BlankActivity.this);
       startActivity(i,options.toBundle());
   }
   else {
       startActivity(i);
   }
}
```

### Most important!

put your `setAnimation()`method before `setContentView()` method otherwise the animation will not work.
So your `AllCastActivity.java`should look like this

```
 class AllCastActivity extends AppcompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);

      setAnimation();

      setContentView(R.layout.all_cast_activity);

      .......
   }

   private void setAnimation(){

      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>20) {
      Slide slide = new Slide();
      slide.setSlideEdge(Gravity.LEFT);
      ..........
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully, it will work for you.

```
startActivityForResult( intent, 1 , ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.slide_out_bottom,R.anim.slide_in_bottom).toBundle());
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin example:

```
    private val SPLASH_DELAY: Long = 1000

    internal val mRunnable: Runnable = Runnable {
        if (!isFinishing) {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
            finish()
        }
    }


   private fun navigateToHomeScreen() {
        //Initialize the Handler
        mDelayHandler = Handler()

        //Navigate with delay
        mDelayHandler!!.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_DELAY)

    }

    public override fun onDestroy() {

        if (mDelayHandler != null) {
            mDelayHandler!!.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
        }

        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

put animations in anim folder:

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p">
</translate>
```

USAGE

```
  navigateToHomeScreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `overridePendingTransition` in `startActivity` instead of `onCreate`. At least, that works for me!

See a full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711666/activity-navigation-custom-animation-with-popenter-and-popexit-like-fragments). It's including an (reverse) animation onBackPressed, so while returning to the previous activity! In your specific example (fade-in and -out) that might be unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Slide animation can be applied to activity transitions by calling overridePendingTransition and passing animation resources for enter and exit activities.

Slide animations can be slid right, slide left, slide up and slide down.

**Slide up**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

**Slide down**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <scale
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_up);

See [activity transition animation examples](http://www.zoftino.com/android-activity-transition-animation-examples) for more activity transition examples.