# Is it possible to swipe up to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe

I have an activity which contains a `ViewPager` which lets me swipe between four pages and a `RelativeLayout` at the bottom containing tabs for the pages. I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that when I drag the bottom `RelativeLayout` up it starts a new activity ending the `ViewPager` activity.

Added horrible diagram to help explain

[image]

Comment: try [this](http://androidexample.com/Swipe_screen_left__right__top_bottom/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118)

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you.

[slide up xml animation on change activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912277/slide-up-xml-animation-on-change-activity-in-android)

You can just change the animations X and Y values to create Slide Up animation on startActivity.