# How to Add Enter and Exit Animations to Specific Activity in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Let's say I have 3 activities: A, B, and C. The order goes like A to B to C. I want to add enter and exit animations to B. When I open B from A, B should have slide up animation. When I go from B to C, B should have slide down animation. Here is my code:

In the Activity A:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, B.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,  R.anim.no_animation); // working, I can see B is opening with slide up animation
```

In the Activity B:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_animation,  R.anim.slide_down); // not working, slide down is not applied to B
```

I also tried settings window enter and exit animations in the theme XML file of B. But it is not working.

Any solution?

Comment: Does this [how-to-apply-slide-animation-between-two-activities-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243557/how-to-apply-slide-animation-between-two-activities-in-android) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass 0 for `no_animation`

As Document said,

> Params:
>
> - enterAnim – A resource ID of the animation resource to use for the incoming activity. Use 0 for no animation.
> - exitAnim – A resource ID of the animation resource to use for the outgoing activity. Use 0 for no animation.

Try with pass 0 in parameter instead of `R.anim.no_animation`. It might show Slide-Down animatation for `Activity B`.

```java
startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_down);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use activities navigation using navigation component. In navigation component, we can define enter and exit animation. Please check the possibilites.

Comment: Navigation component is for fragments.